# Pass the indexpath value to FirstViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am using two viewcontrollers in my application. I have a button in my FirstViewController. When I select the button, it pushes the SecondViewController. I have a tableView in the SecondViewController. How to pass the indexpath value of the selected index in the tableView of SecondViewController to the FirstViewController, without using NSUserDefaults? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Protocols. You can pass the value back to the parent view using delegates.

It is always better to use delegates (@Protocol) to callback the parent view controller.

A simple tutorial on that can be found [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html)

Answer (score 1):

You always can access FirstViewController from SecondViewController access through -[UIViewController parentController] for example, if FirstViewController has property named `selectedRowInSecondController`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 FirstViewController *firstViewController = [self parentController];
 firstViewController.selectedRowInSecondController = [indexPath row];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In second viewcontroller in that creating the property of the variable.

```
@property(nonatomic,readwrite)NSUInteger indexValue;
```

then

```
@synthesize indexValue= _indexValue;
```

Then After Create the object of the secondVctr in the firstviewcontroller;

```
#import "secondViewcontroller.h"

    @interface firstviewcontroller : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic,strong)secondViewcontroller *objsecondViewcontroller;


@synthesize objsecondViewcontroller =_objsecondViewcontroller;
```

following code is put into the when the user tapped on the button that event.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    

    CountDown *controller = [[secondvctr alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondvctr" bundle:nil];
    self.objsecondViewcontroller.indexValue=indexPath
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSNotifications to pass values.